# Be used to + object + passive gerund

Tags: grammar, word-usage

to be/get used to doing something - is a kind of active construction.

to be/get used to something being done - is it the right way to talk about getting used to something that is passive?

I'm used to the announcement being repeated.

Comment: Sure it's okay - *I'm used to being treated with respect,* for example. Switching to a different "patient" noun for the subordinate clause (*I'm used to **my wife** being treated with respect,* as opposed to ***me***) is much less common, but I can't see any *syntactic* problem with that version.

Comment: I agree. Grammatically, this is fine. 
In some cases, you can also use *have* instead of *being* + past participle: *I'm used to my meals being delivered for me* = *I'm used to having my meals delivered.* In some cases, of course, this doesn't work or changes the meaning.